# Excel File Corrupted and File extension issue (Python issue when merging multiple excel files)

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I am trying to take ~30 excel files in a directory on my windows PC and have it merged into 1 giant excel file right now. Later, I wanted to remove unnecessary columns, cells, and rows. But one thing at a time.

My first time executing this code, I was able to create a large excel file with 16,000 KB and probably 180,000 rows. However, several attempts after I got the File Corrupt and Extension error and Excel couldn't open my file. It shows up as a 0 KB file when I run the script. How can I stop the file from getting corrupted? I have tried changing it to .xls, and changing the security and trust center settings and I still got this error.[Excel Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84mhK.png) [Combine File showing as 0 KB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkIeG.png)

I am an amateur coder here is my code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def main():
    
    cwd = os.path.abspath('C:\\Users\\Documents\\Reports\\July') 
    files = os.listdir(cwd)  
    
    df_total = pd.DataFrame()
    for file in files:                         # loop through Excel files
        if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
            excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(file)
            sheets = excel_file.sheet_names
            for sheet in sheets:               # loop through sheets inside an Excel file
                df = excel_file.parse(sheet_name = sheet)
                df_total = df_total.append(df)
    df_total.to_excel('combined_file.xlsx')
    
   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You're only passing the filename, not the full directory, to `pd.ExcelFile()`.

Comment: Hi John, can you elaborate? How do I pass the full directory?

Comment: Use `os.path.join()` to join a directory and filename together.  `pd.ExcelFile(os.path.join(cwd, file))`

Comment: So I tried doing what you suggested and still got the corrupt file error on MS Excel... what is causing this?

Comment: Now I am getting "ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually."

Comment: Is the file still zero bytes?

Comment: Yes it still is...

Comment: I feel like I have tried anything not sure how else to fix this

Comment: Can you try this code on a different directory with only a few xls files, and see if that works?